# Node.js express next error handler

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code looks like this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if (id==8) {
        res.send('0e');
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  res.send(500, '<h1>Oops! what happened?</h1>');
});
```

So. the next() function is called the message **Ooops! what happened** should appear on screen but instead a message **' Cannot GET / ' appears**

Answer (score 1):

You can use node.js built in uncaught exception, just put this code inside your server.js

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
   console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);    
   //you can also email this error
});
```

or follow this link

http://masashi-k.blogspot.com/2012/12/express3-global-error-handling-domain.html

Answer (score 0):

Error handlers are only called if `next()` was called with an Error object.

So to trigger your error handler you'd have to do:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if (id==8) {
        res.send('0e');
    } else {
        next(new Error('Fake error occurred'));
    }
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  res.send(500, '<h1>Oops! what happened?</h1>');
});
```